# Reset ACLs on Mac OSX Files and Directories

Tags: macos, directory, file-permissions, acl, chmod

How can ACLs or file permissions / rights on Mac OSX be reset for single files / folders / directories?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should go fine using...
`sudo CHMOD -R -N MYFOLDER`

In my case it did not work. I tried using the file info dialog and still had problems. So if you want to remove / reset all permissions / rights / acls on a folder, **just ZIP it and unzip it** to a fresh directory.